# Is it possible to change the animation length of many Rigid Bodies?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, rigid-body-simulation

I have made a scene with many Rigid Body objects (1500 rectangular solids), which all operate correctly. However I now want to lengthen the animation period from the default 250 frames to a more reasonable range of around 2000. The issue I am having is the timeline continues like normal, but the *Rigid Body* animation hangs on the 250th frame. Is it possible fix this issue, and preferably be able to to change all of these objects at once?

Comment: No need unless you really want to. Duplicates aren't necessarily a bad thing, as they increase the chance that someone searching on google will find one of these posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Properties->Scene->Rigid_Body_Cache.

Change the end from 250 to 2000

[image]