# Why does the blue line in the timeline cause errors if I render past it?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

How can I reset this blue line? Because an error occurs when I render this file, the footage stops moving after the blue line ends (= frame ~250)

Comment: Thank you, but how can I do that? And does it also expand the frame duration? For example to 1000?

Comment: Please edit your question and add information on your scene. The blue line indicates caching,  that could be caching of many different things (physics, particles, etc) we don't know what kind of project you are dealing with.

Comment: maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46820/rigid-simulation-freezes-at-frame-250

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34285/wind-field-freeze-at-frame-250-where-can-it-be-changed http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19196/is-it-possible-to-change-the-animation-length-of-many-rigid-bodies or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6741/physics-are-not-simulated-past-a-certain-frame

Comment: Thank you, it was a waving flag, and I used a cloth simulation like Timaroberts said. I had to change the end frame at Physics -> Cloth Cache

Comment: Now everything is solved